# Cannot click and hold element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like click and hold the bar in a webpage and move it to the right.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Ie('IEDriverServer.exe')
url = 'https://verify.meituan.com/v2/web/general_page?action=spiderindefence&requestCode=507e224b8f0f447793ad3a03830984c8&platform=1000&adaptor=auto&succCallbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Foptimus-mtsi.meituan.com%2Foptimus%2FverifyResult%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.dianping.com%252Fsearch%252Fkeyword%252F1%252F0_%2525E5%252590%25258D%2525E5%252588%25259B%2525E4%2525BC%252598%2525E5%252593%252581%252F10&theme=dianping'
browser.get(url)
slider = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='yodaBoxWrapper']//div[@id='yodaMoveingBar']")
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(xoffset=50, yoffset=0).perform()
```

The bar does not move.

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Simply replace `chrome` options with `ie` options. Add a user-agent. Add time.sleep after get url. That's it. `from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options`

Comment: You might need to wait for slider to be clickable. But, anyway, you won't be able to complete captcha as these actions should be recognized as script-based

Comment: I tried to execute the code after 5 min but the bar did not move.

Comment: @Chan Did you add a user agent?

Comment: @ Abrar Ahmed. I haven't added user-agent.

Comment: @Chan Some sites block access to automated browsers, it's a good idea to add one. It worked perfect with chrome. I don't see why it wouldn't work with IE.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to do some opeartion on web element, if you see manually how site loads than you will find that it takes time to render HTML components on page.

You need to wait until element is rendered on the page and an extra check to make sure its clickable which you can do with below code. For full list of best practices please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/415749).

```
slider = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='yodaBoxWrapper']//div[@id='yodaMoveingBar']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='yodaBoxWrapper']//div[@id='yodaMoveingBar']")))
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(xoffset=200, yoffset=0).perform()
```

Below is the full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Ie('IEDriverServer.exe')
url = 'https://verify.meituan.com/v2/web/general_page?action=spiderindefence&requestCode=507e224b8f0f447793ad3a03830984c8&platform=1000&adaptor=auto&succCallbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Foptimus-mtsi.meituan.com%2Foptimus%2FverifyResult%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.dianping.com%252Fsearch%252Fkeyword%252F1%252F0_%2525E5%252590%25258D%2525E5%252588%25259B%2525E4%2525BC%252598%2525E5%252593%252581%252F10&theme=dianping'
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
slider = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='yodaBoxWrapper']//div[@id='yodaMoveingBar']")))
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='yodaBoxWrapper']//div[@id='yodaMoveingBar']")))
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(xoffset=200, yoffset=0).perform()
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have used `IE 11` and IE driver version `3.150.1.0 (32 bit)` to test this and it works fine in it, if you can elaborate are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I use IE 11. The code finished successfully but the bar does not move